# My questions keep getting down-voted; is it revenge down-voting?

Tags: support, status-completed, down-votes

[Nine questions of mine](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/252/kiamlaluno?tab=reputation) have been down-voted in less than fifteen minutes, and another one has been down-voted one minute ago. It sounds like revenge down-voting to me.

Can anything be done, about that?

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty flagrant. They should get reverted by tomorrow.

Comment: "keep getting", @kiamlaluno, "keep getting" :-)

Comment: @psmears Hey! Keeping to use the infinite is a big effort from my side. I just do it to be sure you don't confuse me with somebody else; am I not thoughtful?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Ah, I see. If we see you say "keep using", we'll know you've been captured by the enemy, and will send out a rescue mission at once! :-)

Comment: @psmears Exactly! _Puts a check close to "Mission 1 accomplished."_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The revenge downvotes have been identified as such and removed by the system. The mods know who it was. Please don't do that again.

Comment: Just to see if I understand this correctly. Do you mean that the SE system *automatically* detects revenge downvoters and then notifies the mods?  If so, what are the criteria? Ten downvotes and you are out? Something else?  I ask because I've started to get some I think.